# Get rows from cache in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse, bids, control-flow

I am saving error data along the path of my data collection SSIS package into a cache component.

At the end of control flow I'd like to read out all the collected data and direct them into a script component to parse the collected data.

How can I retrieve the data stored in a cache component at a point of control flow execution to process it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "cache component", do you mean the SSIS [Cache Transform transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895264.aspx), or something else? I've never used it myself, but the documentation for the Cache Transform says that it's intended to be used with the Lookup Transformation, so it isn't a general purpose caching mechanism.

Personally I would write the error data to a regular text file and then parse it. That gives you a persistent copy of the data that can be read by any tool that you like, even outside SSIS.

Comment: But for performance reasons, you might be interested in using the Raw file destination. +1 for hunting down the docs though